# Why is my Singleton not maintaining it's set value?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, singleton

I have an app where I'm using a singleton; here is the code in the .h file:

```
@interface SingletonServicesType : NSObject  {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *globalServicesType;

+ (id)sharedInstance;
@end
```

Here is the code in the .m file:

```
//-------------------------------------------
//--  SingletonServicesType
@implementation SingletonServicesType  {  

}

@synthesize globalServicesType;  //  rename

//--  sharedInstance  --
+ (id)sharedInstance  {

static dispatch_once_t dispatchOncePredicate = 0;
__strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
dispatch_once(&dispatchOncePredicate, ^{
    _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
});

return _sharedObject;
}

-(id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    globalServicesType = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

@end
```

Here is the code where I set the initial value of singleton in AppDelegate.m:

```
    //  set services
SingletonServicesType *sharedInstance = [SingletonServicesType sharedInstance];  //  initialize
if(preferenceData.aServicesType == nil)  {
    sharedInstance.globalServicesType = 0;  //  (0) is the default
    preferenceData.aServicesType = 0;  //  here too...
    [localContext MR_saveNestedContexts];  //  save it...
}
else
    sharedInstance.globalServicesType = preferenceData.aServicesType;  //  0 = default (nails), 1 = custom

NSLog(@"\n\n1-sharedInstance.globalServicesType: %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt: (sharedInstance.globalServicesType)]);  //  shows a value of '0'
```

When I immediately examine the value of the singleton in another class, it's 'null'!  Here's that code:

```
    SingletonServicesType *sharedInstance = [SingletonServicesType sharedInstance];  //  initialize
NSLog(@"\n\n2-sharedInstance.globalServicesType: %@", sharedInstance.globalServicesType);  //  shows a value of 'null'
```

I don't understand why the value is maintaining the setting?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are assigning zero to `NSNumber*`. You need to assign `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]` or `@0`, otherwise the integer is interpreted as an address:

```
sharedInstance.globalServicesType = @0; // <<== Here
```